# memory leak: unable to break on a memory allocation number

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I'm trying to locate a memory leak issue.

My project is an ATL based dialog project, that uses DirectShow and the standard library.

I get a total of 45 memory leaks in my program, all 24 bytes each.

I've #define'd _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC etc in my stdafx.h, along with DEBUG_NEW to get the file and line numbers for each of the memory leaks.

However, no file line numbers are printed.  The memory blocks are all "normal" blocks and look like this:

```
{180} normal block at 0x003E6008, 24 bytes long. Data: <  >  _>   > W   > A0 AE 3E 00 B0 5F 3E 00 A0 AE 3E 00 57 00 00 00
```

I've tried adding the following line to the start of _tWinMain()

```
_CrtSetBreakAlloc(180);
```

in order to break on the allocation, but the debugger doesn't break at all.

Can anyone give me any insight into how I might track down the elusive memory leaks?

Finally, here's my _tWinMain() - I call _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() just before exiting.

```
int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE /*hPrevInstance*/, LPTSTR lpstrCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
    _CrtSetBreakAlloc(180);

    HRESULT hRes = ::CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hRes));


    ::DefWindowProc(NULL, 0, 0, 0L);
    AtlInitCommonControls(ICC_BAR_CLASSES);

    //HINSTANCE hInstRich = ::LoadLibrary(CRichEditCtrl::GetLibraryName());

    hRes = _Module.Init(NULL, hInstance);
    ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hRes));

    int nRet = Run(lpstrCmdLine, nCmdShow);

    _Module.Term();
    ::CoUninitialize();

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();

    return nRet;
}
```

Comment: do you have anything in global namespace? sometimes some destructors have not been called when you check for memleaks. another way is just to do it the old fashioned way, commenting out code to localize where.

Comment: Btw, yes, if you have any static variables that point to any heap-allocated stuff and they are not explicitly delete'd before dumping leaks then leaks will surely be reported.

Comment: I'll add this to a reply for formatting purposes...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two suggestions.

Firstly, what gets constructed before `main` (or equivalent) starts gets destroyed after `main` finishes. Calling `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` at the end of `main` can give you false positives. (Or are they false negatives?) Global objects' destructors have yet to run, and `atexit` callbacks have yet to run, so the leak output will include allocations that have simply yet to be correctly freed.

(I suspect this is why your global objects are appearing to leak. There may well be nothing wrong with the code, and indeed it's quite possibly cleaning itself up properly -- the cleanup code has simply yet to run when `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` is being called.)

What you need to do instead is to direct the runtime library to call `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` for you, right at the end, after all the `atexit` callbacks and global object destructors have finished. Then you'll only see the genuine leaks. This snippet will do the trick. Stick at at the start of `main`:

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG)|_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
```

Secondly, if the above reveals genuine leaks from stuff that runs before `main`, you can do a bit of trickery to get some of your own code running pretty much before anything else gets a look in. Then you can set `_crtBreakAlloc` before any allocations happen. Just pop the following code in a .cpp file of its own:

```
#include <crtdbg.h>

#ifdef _DEBUG

#pragma warning(disable:4074)//initializers put in compiler reserved initialization area
#pragma init_seg(compiler)//global objects in this file get constructed very early on

struct CrtBreakAllocSetter {
    CrtBreakAllocSetter() {
        _crtBreakAlloc=<allocation number of interest>;
    }
};

CrtBreakAllocSetter g_crtBreakAllocSetter;

#endif//_DEBUG
```

(I suspect that code in the compiler's init segment may well run before `stdin` and `stdout` and the like are initialised, and certainly before any global objects are constructed, so you may have difficulty doing anything more complicated than the above!)

(For what little it's worth, I'm of the opinion these days, and have been for some time now, that allocation before `main` starts is almost always a bad thing. Makes it hard to clean up after oneself, and difficult to keep track of what's going on. It's certainly convenient, but you always seem to end up paying for it later. That's advice that's much easier to hand out than it is to implement, though, particularly as part of a larger team.)

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I completely agree that allocation before main is a bad thing.  

I changed the program to allocate the global objects on the heap and this cut down many of the memory leaks.  The few remaining were just carelessness on my part.

I found your extra cpp file interesting - I'd not read an example of using CrtBreakAllocSetter before, and I'll certainly add it to my toolset...

thanks

Comment: Good suggestion.  I still have 100s of leaks when using this method.  I'm not going to set a break point on each of these.  Of the 10 or so that I've randomly selected to use with _CrtSetBreakAlloc(), there's no resulting break.  Some of the data in these leaked blocks suggests the memory is allocated in a dll.  First I tested if I saw the break at malloc.  That worked.  I can't imagine what else it may be (aside from false positives).

Comment: This is exactly the problem: http://pklab.net/?&id=397&lang=EN&t=False-memory-leaks-with-OpenCV-e-MFC-on-Visual-Studio

Answer (score 0):

I had a couple of global variables (lookup tables that returned CString references to error messages) that I've removed from the program.  As soon as I did - no memory leaks.

Thanks for your comments folks.

Interesting - I'll have to investigate a different way to implement error lookup.

I was doing something like:

```
CString sError = "error at line x: " + g_map.lookup(hrError);
```

The error map is implemented as an object that wraps access to an std::map, and it's destructor work fine.  When I allocate this map object on the heap, and deallocate it, it reports no memory leaks.  Maybe its the way I'm concatenating CString....

Comment: I understand the purity of wanting your code to be leak free.  Just keep in mind that as long as (1) you don't have a long-running, on-demand application (e.g., a service that's available 24/7/365) and (2) the memory leaks are finite, it's not absolutely necessary that you fix them.

Comment: Hi Matt - on the contrary - NEVER allow a memory leak no matter what the circumstances are. It's a best practice issue, and in the long run, when your app develops even more, you won't have to chase these leaks which might cause even bigger problems.

Comment: @Poni, I agree with the best practice sentiment.  But I still stand by my original statement that under certain circumstances, a finite number of memory leaks are permissible.

Comment: I think both are valid points.  According to the altimeter book (http://www.amazon.co.uk/Windows-PRO-Developer-Jeffrey-Nasarre-Christophe/dp/0735624240/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1277760332&sr=8-2), the OS will clean up any memory leaks when a program exits, so as long as you're certain they won't increase, it should be okay to leave a few stray bytes to the OS to clean up.

However, that's not my style, I'd prefer to clean up all the leaks.

But then the memory leak I was working on was part of a windows service, that after 20 minutes consumed over 2Gb of RAM and crashed.

Comment: @MattDavis: The problem is not with the one-shot leaks themselves (as the OS will reclaim the memory) but with the distraction they cause, actually preventing you from seeing new leaks that you introduce (it's more a cognitive problem than anything else) ...

Comment: ... It's essentially the same with warnings: IMO the right attitude is to have 0 warnings, even if that means silencing the ones you have analyzed and rightfully accept as "false positives". While it's easy enough to fix warnings (either by fixing the code or silencing using e.g. a (void)foo for an unused variable) memleaks cannot be silenced that way. So the best option is to prevent them from happening at all.

Comment: @Tibo, I don't disagree.  There are many reasons for addressing memory leaks, but strictly speaking, it is not always necessary.  For example, my project uses some home-grown tools for testing various aspects of the delivered product.  These tools do not undergo the same level of rigor applied to our product.  Thus, spending time fixing things such as memory leaks, if they were to occur, couldn't be justified.  Yes, err on the side of fixing them as they occur, but recognize that they aren't the end of the world in every situation.